# Call a new activity in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to create a simple app for a college project, it is becoming frustrating. Every time I correct an error 6 more pop up. Can some one please help me.

This Box is asking for more information... so basically I would like to create 4 Activities, Main, age4to10, age11to15,age15to18. I need to be able to click on a button and call the relative Activity from the `Main.class`. But each time I debug I get errors I simply do not understand how to fix.

Each of the Activities will host a spinner with a toy selection from a category chosen by the user. (Don't even get me started on spinners)

I would appreciate users not editing down my post, as I consider all the information in here relevant to the issues I am having. As an aside.... I have very little Java training so I will need examples of corrections you may have to offer.

Thanks.

```
package com.example.android.skillsdemoVT;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;

    @Override

    /* button1 */

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View viewById;
        viewById = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick1(View v)
    {
        {
                button1click1();
        }
    }
    public void button1click1()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, age4to10.class));
    }

    /* Button2 */

    public void onClick2(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View viewById;
        viewById = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void button2click1()
    {
        {
            button2click1();

        }

    }


    public void() 
    {
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, age11to15.class));
        }
    }

    /* button3 */

   public void onClick3(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View viewById;
        viewById = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        {
            button3click1();
        }

    }

    public void button3click1()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, age15to18.class));
    }

}



MY XML 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tree1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tree1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp" android:text="Welcome to Santa's workshop."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please let Santa know how old you are!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/welcome" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#b12b2b"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Age 4-10"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="age4to10"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#b12b2b"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Age 11-14"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="age11to15"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#b12b2b"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Age 15-17"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="age15to18"

        />

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: People are downvoting because your question doesn't follow the guidelines set out here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's ok.. I didn't realize there were rules for asking questions.....

Comment: Just a bit of advice, before you ask a question about why your code isn't working, try and condense it down to the smallest form possible where the error is still present.  This often debugs the problem away by itself.

Comment: Ok I will do that next time I have a question, thanks for the advice!

any ideas on what is actually happening in the debugger?

Comment: You haven't posted any errors.  I'm not going to read that wall of code without some indication of what is wrong...

Comment: I thought If I posted the lot, it could be copy pasted into your own compiler and you can see the errors for yourself. but never mind I can tell your busy.

Error:(58, 12) error: class, interface, or enum expected

Error:(60, 68) error: <identifier> expected

Error:(60, 69) error: illegal start of type

Error:(60, 70) error: <identifier> expected

Error:(60, 71) error: ';' expected

Hope that means something to you... because it's all German to me

Comment: @LukePark your advice helped, it was a "button1click1" naming clash, I have working code now. I need to clean my eyeballs.

Comment: You all must feel very powerful down voting this question, I hope  more of you do, but only if you can offer some help or advice before doing so

Down voting a new comer who has already apologized for the format of his question only encourages users to find other places to source solutions
If you don't want to answer that's fine, but clicking the down arrow before you leave is shi**ing on up and coming coders. Is this the way this community treats it's members? Is this the way to help a new generation of coders to stick with it?

I won't come back here with a question to get Shi* on again .i..

Comment: They aren't downvoting as a personal jab at you, the downvotes are because this question doesn't help others. StackOverflow is a source of information for *everyone*, not just those who ask questions. Your question doesn't help anyone because it doesn't adhere to the guidelines. Don't take it personally! StackOverflow is a great place to learn, just make sure you understand the rules and structure.

Comment: Are you serious? I have to word my question in a format that pleases the whole community? There are dozens of sites out there which actually answer questions posed to the community, some people answer as teachers, others as fellow learners BUT they all answer, instead of saying. "your question displeases me... go away" all the comments on this question and not a single attempt to tackle the question, but many edits on syntax, tags and grammer. This is not what I came here for...

Comment: Just remember that the source of your problem was literally a spelling mistake.  Do you really think a question like this belongs here?  Once you become a bit more familiar with programming you will understand why people have downvoted and commented as such.

Comment: ran out of space... and I think... this question does help beginners in Android Studio on the basis that linking activities to button onClick commands in the XML page is a fundamental must have skill set, and when I came here for help, I got corrections to my questions, and no answer to be seen anywhere. I know people don't want to hand hold a newbie. Fine np. but for the love of god, if you must post a comment, at least reference the problem, and Luke, this is not directed at you, you were the only one to offer anything at all. the other three people who down voted and left make me sick...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(storedActivity, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
storedActivity.startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```